# OpenGL ES Texture streaming or mapping

Tags: c#, ios, opengl-es, xamarin.ios

**Situation**

I have a video stream coming from a native library in iOS. I'm trying to display the image in an `iPhoneOSGameView` using `glTexImage2D` and `glTexSubImage2D` for updates. I can update subregions of the image, I receive a structure that tells me which rectangle has to be updated on the gpu.

**The issue**

Framerate is quite low. After much profiling both in OpenGLES and the application code, I have concluded that the application usually is waiting on the texture upload. The slow function is `glClear`, but I suspect there's an intrinsic `glFlush` in there.

**My question**

I've seen some people talking about `glMapBuffer` that could allow me to stream the video directly to the texture in user-space. I've looked at pixel buffer objects, but they require OpenGLES 3.0 or an extension in 2.0. Is there an efficient way (for mobile) to stream a texture with minimal memory copying OR a way to transfer the texture from different thread?

**Additional information**

I'm working in C# Xamarin and I'm testing on different devices such as an iPod Touch Gen3, a iPad Air 2 and a iPad Pro 12".

Answer (score 0):

> there an efficient way (for mobile) to stream a texture with minimal memory copying

Most operating systems have some media framework which allows import of images directly using the EGL_image_external extension avoiding the need to upload. I'm not sure how it works on iOS, but I strongly suspect it should be possible. It's OS-specific unfortunately, so no standard way of doing it.

> OR a way to transfer the texture from different thread?

Just create two GL Contexts in the same share group.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandOpenGLES/ConcurrencyandOpenGLES.html